# pushing json arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I am customizing some `jQuery` plugin, and I have an error message I can't understand

```
        var totHistory=0;
        var positions = new Array();
        $('.someclass').each(function(index){
           var tmp = $(this).val();
           addHistory({id:tmp});
        });

        function addHistory(obj)
        {
            /* Gets called on page load for each comment, and on comment submit */
            totHistory++;
            positions.push(obj.id);
        }
```

At the very first iteration through `.someClass`, I get this message

```
Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

Could someone explain why ?

Comment: Should work. - works for me http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kG7B4/

Comment: The scope seems right, check if you are overwritting or deleting your var positions anywhere. Basically 'push' is a prototype method of array objects, the error means that 'positions' in your case isn't and array object but undefined, and as undefined it donesn't have the method 'push'.

Comment: Which element are you referring in .someclass because val won't work on every element.

Comment: Maybe telling/tagging the plugin you are trying to modify or showing more code we will be more able to help you, I don't really think the error is in that chunk of code

Comment: Is all this code inside any function? because is so, var positions would not be in the global scope as @SteveP suggested on his answer, I thought it was at root level

Comment: This is obviously not the complete code and/or setup, as @mplungjan says, the way you present the problem should work.

Comment: Can you join here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40028/room-for-arup-rakshit-and-mpapis

Answer (score 0):

You should either send `positions` as a parameter or declare it in a scope accesible for `addHistory`. You should not declare it without the var keyword as that is considered a bad practice.

Try my first suggestion as that one is the only one I can help you with without knowing the structure of your other js code.

Comment: In the code example of the OP, `positions` **is** declared in a scope accessible for `addHistory`. Also, it is declared using `var`.

Comment: Yes, it appears it is, but if that's the case, that error should not be appearing, maybe he omitted code. The `var` keyword advice was because of the other answers people are posting.